# Swiping to delete cell moving cell's custom UILabels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell and I have added custom UILabels to the cell. I implemented UITableView's delete methods to allow deleting of the cell when it is swiped. The problem is, when swiped, the cell

- Automatically moved custom UILabels to the left. How can I remove this feature or change the extent to which they are moved to the left?
- Only certain UILabels are moved. Not all of them? Why is that and how can I change this behvaiour to make all UILabels/UIViews move to the left instead of a select few?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the layout properties of the label have something to do with it, but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hmm that's a good idea. I'll check and confirm that.

Comment: if you want to move labels automatically than use autoresize mask property.